# Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead

Tags: html, vue.js

I am having trouble to understand how to pass a value to vue through html, it always gives me this error: Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead

Edit: I want to pass the value "country" to the vue instance, this does not work, can someone give me an example on HTML and vue side please??

This is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="image-slider" :country="@{{country}}">
<template id="slider-template">
<p>
<a class="featured-providers-arrow-left" @click="prevRow"><img src="{{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'arrow.png']) }}"/></a>
</p>
<a class="featured-providers-arrow-right" @click="nextRow"><img src="{{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'arrow.png']) }}"/></a>
</template>
</div>
```

VUE

```
new Vue({
el: '#image-slider',
  data: {
    providers: []
  },
  mounted(){
    this.country = this.$el.attributes.country.value;
    this.$http.get('/provider-' + this.country).then(response => response.data = this.providers);/*this.providers = response.data);*/
  },
  currentNumber: 0,
  timer:null
}
```

Comment: Just add colon before src attributes in images.

Answer (score 3):

Text interpolations are no longer supported in Vuejs. [As explained here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Interpolation-within-Attributes-removed):

> ###Interpolation within Attributes removed
>
> Interpolation within attributes is no longer valid.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <button class="btn btn-{{ size }}"></button>
> ```

> Should either be updated
> to use an inline expression:

> ```
> <button v-bind:class="'btn btn-' + > size"></button>
> ```

---

So, this basically means unlike in Vuejs 1.x where this syntax would be valid:

```
<img src="{{someValue}}">
```

In 2.x it is no longer supported. So you must change it to:

```
<img :src="someValue">
```

Comment: Not entirely, I have this value here now:
:country="{{ $country }}" as in my code where $country is an object in the style of country => 'string' 

I want to pass this object to vue, however if for example the string is 'Sweden' it gives me this error message:

"[Vue warn]: Property or method "sweden" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. 

But the property I want to pass is the object not the value "sweden" what do I need to do here?

Comment: You can't do `:country` the colon must be attached to known html attributes like `value`, `src`, `class`, `disabled` etc... if you want to use/pass data called `country` you have to pass it like this `:data-country='country'`

Comment: I tried using :data-country='country' but I received the same error, it seems to be quite complicated to pass a simple object value to vue using blade ..... :(((

Comment: Do you maybe have a fiddle for me? :))

Comment: You want to get the country?

Comment: I want to pass an object along these lines here: ['country' => "sweden"]
So 'sweden' as a string should be passed to the vue instance